# Redis lock implementation

Tags: ruby, locking, redis

Considering I'm **not** implementing **distributed** lock mechanism, is this code correct and clear?

```
class RedisLock
  class NotAcquired < StandardError; end

  def initialize(redis)
    @redis = redis
  end

  def lock(key, expiration_ms)
    val = SecureRandom.random_number(100000000000000000).to_s

    if @redis.set(key, val, nx: true, px: expiration_ms)
      yield
      unlock(key, val)
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

  def lock!(*args, &block)
    unless lock(*args, &block)
      raise NotAcquired.new("Could not acquire lock with #{args}")
    end
  end

  def unlock(key, val)
    check_and_delete = <<-LUA
      if redis.call('get', KEYS[1]) == KEYS[2] then
        redis.call('del', KEYS[1])
      end
    LUA

    @redis.eval(check_and_delete, [key, val])
  end
end


RedisLock.new(Redis.current).lock!('key', 10000) { do_something }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stab at clarifying the intent without changing any of the functionality. I didn't try to run it or anything, so don't hold me to syntax.

```
# handles locking and unlocking redis for a particular operation
class RedisLock
  # thrown when a lock cannot be acquired
  class NotAcquired < StandardError; end

  # since the redis key and ms are used in pretty much every method,
  # might as well go ahead and pass them in the constructor.
  # set defaults here if there are defaults that make sense.
  # make a yardoc comment and describe what these all are.
  def initialize(redis: Redis.current, nx: true, redis_key:, expiration_ms:)
    @redis = redis
    @redis_key = redis_key
    @expiration_ms = expiration_ms
    @nx = nx
  end

  # call it with_lock instead of lock
  # to make it more apparent it accepts a block
  def with_lock!
    raise(NotAcquired, "Could not acquire lock with #{args}") unless lock
    yield
    unlock(redis_key, random_lock_number)
    true # do you really need to return true here?
  end

  def with_lock
    with_lock!
  rescue NotAcquired
    false
  end

  private

  # set instance variables in the initializer, but never call them directly.
  attr_reader :redis, :redis_key, :expiration_ms, :nx

  def lock
    redis.set(redis_key, random_lock_number, nx: nx, px: expiration_ms)
  end

  # number is a little decieving here when you call `.to_s` at the end.
  # can you use SecureRandom.uuid instead?
  def random_lock_number
    @random_lock_number ||= SecureRandom.random_number(100_000_000_000_000_000).to_s
  end

  # no need for this to be exposed publicly.
  # calling eval directly is usually a bad idea.
  def unlock
    redis.eval(redis_check_and_delete, [redis_key, random_lock_number])
  end

  def redis_check_and_delete
    <<-LUA
      if redis.call('get', KEYS[1]) == KEYS[2] then
        redis.call('del', KEYS[1])
      end
    LUA
  end
end
```

And to call it:

```
RedisLock.new(redis_key: 'key', expiration_ms: 10000).with_lock! { do_something }
```

Comment: Hi @Chris! Thanks you for the answer! Though I cannot agree with the suggested improvements. The general concern about it is that the new object cannot be re-used with another key. Moreover it even cannot be re-used with the same key. I also have minor concerns (like `nx` in parameters makes no sense), but this is not so important after the first point.

Comment: object instantiation is free. You have no need to to re-use the single object. the Redis connection is already passed in. you've even named the class `RedisLock` and not something like `RedisLockFactory`. The major takeaway here, if you care to take away anything is that your methods are doing too much internally. If you're passing arguments into every single method, that's a code smell. also usually the `!` version of a method is called by the non-bang version instead of the other way around. good luck.